# How to set `uniqueWriterIdentity=true` on sink create

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-logging

I'm getting the following error when trying to create a new sink using the logging [Python SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/logging):

> google.gax.errors.RetryError: RetryError(Exception occurred in retry
>   method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of
>   RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, The destination
>   project must be the same as the sink's project. Use
>   uniqueWriterIdentity=true to allow cross project exports.)>)

I fully understand why I'm getting this error (I'm creating a sink cross-project), but I'm not seeing where I can set `uniqueWriterIdentity` as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.sinks/create).

What am I missing?

```
sink = logging.Client(project=project_id).sink(
            'name',
            'resource.type:*',
            'bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/..')
sink.create()
```

Comment: Writer identity was added very recently in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/4595

Answer (score 0):

Writer identity has been added per [Logging: Unique Writer Identity #4595](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/4595)